# Clicker Heroes Ruby chance?

Tags: clicker-heroes

What is the chance of getting 1 Ruby from a Fish?

Is it a 50% chance, or the chance of not getting a Ruby is higher?

I get only coins more often than I get Rubies.
[image: Ruby]

**What exactly is the chance of Rubies from a fish?**

Comment: I can't find any source for this anywhere. May be  that you have to do some science.

Comment: @Svj0hn no...... **bounty!!** >:D

Comment: I tried figuring this out, but it seems the chance is not linear. In the lower zones I seem to get rubies more often than in higher zones. This is just a gut feeling though. (hence this is not an answer). What I do know for sure is that the chance for a ruby is always less than 50%.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's take a look at the source code, shall we?

The script responsible for (currently) the fish and the bee is `heroclickerlib.managers.HiddenObjectManager`.

Inside that script we find a function `private function onHiderClick(param1:MouseEvent) : void`.
This function is responsible for the on-click event when you click the fish.

```
private function onHiderClick(param1:MouseEvent) : void
  {
     var _loc4_:* = 0;
     var _loc5_:* = NaN;
     var _loc6_:* = NaN;
     this.removeHider();
     if(Rnd.boolean(0.44))
     {
        _loc4_ = 1;
        if(Rnd.boolean(0.04 + this._userData.ancients.doubleRubyPercent / 100))
        {
           _loc4_ = 2;
        }
        this._userData.addRubies(_loc4_,"hidden_object",-1);
        _loc5_ = this._battleManager.display.mouseX;
        _loc6_ = this._battleManager.display.mouseY;
        this._battleManager.uiManager.battleUI.transientEffects.showGeneralMessage(_loc5_,_loc6_,_("+%s Ruby!",_loc4_));
     }
     var _loc2_:Monster = new Monster();
     _loc2_.id = 2;
     _loc2_.level = this._userData.highestFinishedZone + 1;
     var _loc3_:Number = this._userData.getMonsterReward(_loc2_) * 10;
     _loc2_.isBoss = true;
     this._battleManager.itemDropManager.goldSplash(_loc3_,_loc2_,ServerTimeKeeper.instance.timestamp);
     HeroClickerSoundManager.instance.playSoundEffectById(36);
     this._battleManager.uiManager.battleUI.transientEffects.showGeneralMessage(580,152,"Yay!!");
  }
```

Two function calls are important here:

1. `if(Rnd.boolean(0.44))`: this internally checks if a (uniformly distributed) random number is less than 0.44. This evaluates to a chance of nearly exact 44% of *at least one* ruby.
2. `if(Rnd.boolean(0.04 + this._userData.ancients.doubleRubyPercent / 100))`: This rather lengthy call checks if a random number is less than 0.04 + the additional double ruby percentage of your ancients. This means that in 4% of all cases of getting a ruby, you get 2.
   Without any ancients, the chance of getting 2 rubies is about 0.44*0.04=0.0176 => 1.76%

The average amount of rubies you get after 1000 times clicking on the fish is: 444,4 => 44,44%

```
440 times at least one ruby
=>  440*4%  =     11 times 2 rubies = 22    +
=>  440*96% =  422,4 times 1 ruby   = 422,4

==> 444,4 rubies => ~444,4/1000 = 44,44% chance of getting one ruby on average
```

The expected amount of rubies per click is then 0,4444.

I used [JPEXS Free Flash Decompiler](https://www.free-decompiler.com/flash/) to get to the source code.

Comment: Since I'm bad at maths you should probably add what the average chance of getting a ruby is, (incorporate the double chance into the 44% chance)

Comment: You mean the chance of getting only *one* ruby? Getting a ruby at all is 44%. The extra percentage of 4% is just evaluated **after** the logic decided to give you a ruby in general.

Comment: yes I understand, there's a 44% chance of getting either one(96%) or two(4%) rubies, so if you include that stat into one stat, so the chance of getting one ruby would be a bit higher than 44% because sometimes you would get two. Did I explain myself well? otherwise don't worry

Comment: @Aequitas so you mean the chance of getting one ruby *on average*. I'll add that.

Comment: @GiantTree I believe the appropriate term to be the _expected amount of rubies per clickable_.

Comment: @Svj0hn this is the term I searched for. It would be 0,4444 then.

Comment: @GiantTree I made an answer with some calculations regarding the expected value. Feel free to include the correct numbers in your answer if you like.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @GiantTree's otherwise [great answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/234010/117521):

The expected ruby count, `E(R)` from a single clickable is:

`E(R) = 1 * P(1) + 2 * P(2)`, (1)

where `P(x)` is the probability of getting `x` rubies.

Using @GiantTree's information as source, we see that double ruby is rolled for **after** the first one, meaning:

`P(1) = 0.44 - P(2)`,

which means the (1) can be expressed as:

`E(R) = 0.44 - P(2) + 2 * P(2) = 0.44 + P(2)`. (2)

Now, `P(2)` can be calculated by:

`P(2) = 0.44 * (0.04 + DRC)`,

where `DRC` is your *double ruby chance*, expressed as a fraction (so 15% means `DRC = 0.15`).

Finally, we insert this expression into (2):

`E(R) = 0.44 + 0.44(0.04 + DRC) = 0.44 * (1.04 + DRC) = 0.4576 + 0.44 * DRC`.

Or for short:

`E(R) = 0.4576 + 0.44 * DRC`.

This means the base *expected value* is **0.4576** rubies per clickable.

Since the highest value of the `DRC`-boosting ancient is 15%, we get a maximum value (excluding relics) of:

`Emax(R) = 0.4576 + 0.44 * 0.15 = 0.5236`,

meaning the maximum expected ruby yield (again, excluding relics) is **0.5236**.